# getting error on jsonP data

Tags: c#, json, wcf, jsonp

I am trying to get jsonp Data but i am getting error

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost:59672/RestServiceImpl.svc/getallemp',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);//i am getting Error

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
```

below is my json response

```
{"success":"[{\"usercode\":2},{\"usercode\":23},{\"usercode\":24},{\"usercode\":25},{\"usercode\":26},{\"usercode\":27},{\"usercode\":28},{\"usercode\":29},{\"usercode\":30},{\"usercode\":31}]"}
```

then i am getting below error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

i am using WCF Restful Service
below  is Service code

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "getallemp")]
        [return: MessageParameter(Name = "success")]
        string GetAllEmployee();
```

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0POVh.png)

Comment: Can you try using WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098418/producing-json-from-c-webmessagebodystyle-wrapped-or-webmessagebodystyle-bare

Comment: @OguzOzgul,after change i am getting below response {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Comment: where is the response? This does not look like a response to me.

Comment: this i what i get on console.log(date) "{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}"

Comment: @OguzOzgul,on google chrome network i get following ""[{\"usercode\":2},{\"usercode\":23},{\"usercode\":24},{\"usercode\":25},{\"usercode\":26},{\"usercode\":27},{\"usercode\":28},{\"usercode\":29},{\"usercode\":30},{\"usercode\":31}]""

Comment: Oh, you are returning a string, which means you are converting the return value to json yourself, and, also by specifying [return: MessageParameter(Name = "success")], you are causing the return to be like `success: [your array of items]`. Can't you just return the collection itself?

Comment: @OguzOzgul, why i am getting "{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}" ???

Comment: I think that response is what you expect? Do you still get the error?

Comment: Where are you getting that "{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}"

Comment: @OguzOzgul,please check method i am converting datatable to json below is my method

Comment: i am using javascript serlization

Comment: @OguzOzgul,System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

Comment: @OguzOzgul,i am getting when i am trying 
"success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);//i am getting Error

                },"

Comment: @OguzOzgul,Sorry it was coming from ajax error error: function (xhr) {
                    //console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(xhr);
                }

Comment: Answer seem to have nothing to do with the question - so likely something unrelated to the question was causing the issue. Voting to close as "resolved in a manner not likely to help future visitors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```